# Not adding 2 value because of comma(javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, codeigniter

I'm adding 2 value with comma and .00(Ex. 1,200.23 + 2,500.44) but its not adding because textbox has a comma and its required to my system.

It shows NaN because comma is a special symbol char. It working before i add textbox masking(comma and .00)

Here's my code

javascript adding 2 textbox

```
function getTotal(inputTxt, inputTotal) {

$(inputTxt).on('keyup paste', function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(inputTxt).each(function () {
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(inputTotal).val(sum);
})
```

and i'm using textbox masking `$('.ia_val').mask("#,##0.00", {reverse: true});`

and here's the output `getTotal(".ia_val", ".ia_total");`

it always shows NaN because of comma

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove the comma from the string to be able to parse it into a float.

```
sum += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g,''));
```

Comment: @Yettt If I answered your question, please click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it and mark your question as answered.